# Memory leak in Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an old Windows service on .Net2 that is leaking memory.
I took 2 dump files and compared them on perfview - I saw that the problem was is in the Oracle parameters finalizer, then I went through the whole code I could get (50 DLLs) and saw that none of them was disposing the Oracle parameters. I added "using" to every oracle param I saw, Deployed it and it didn't help - compared 2 dumps and again oracle parameters finalizer. I tried to use ants memory profiler to determine which DLL is the cause for this leak but ants runs only on .Net4. So I changed my service config file to run with .Net 4 CLR and now my application is not leaking anymore and is using my old DLLs where oracle parameters are not disposed.
How come upgrading the .Net fixed the problem even though the Oracle parameters weren't disposed?

Comment: Because new .net versions have better garbage collection algorithms.

Comment: think of it this way.. `does a 1950 ford run the same as a 2016 Ford` with newer Technology comes improvements.. `Garbage Collection, using construct, etc.. If you upgraded the .net framework version I don't see how this question can still be an Issue I am voting to close since this is not an issue anymore.

Comment: But how can it be that the dispose didn't help? And without dispose and only upgrading framework helped?